# Вредоносный код в Joomla

Tags: joomla, javascript

В файле index.php шаблона Joomla 1.5 появился левый скрипт. Внутри его какие-то ссылки. При этом пропала возможность редактировать этот файл из административной панели Joomla. Открывается чистое окно. Копирую этот файл на компьютер и просто удаляю этот скрипт, потом обратно заливаю на сервер - сайт перестает работать. Как исправить ситуацию? Большое спасибо.
Вот

```
<?php

/**

* @copyright Copyright (C) 2007 JoomlaPraise. All rights reserved.

*/

// no direct access

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >

<head>

<meta name='yandex-verification' content='48142ee2403b2485' />

<jdoc:include type="head" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/<?php echo $this->params->get('templateTheme'); ?>.css" type="text/css" />

<?php

if(($this->countModules('left') == 0) && ($this->countModules('right') == 0)) { ?>

<style type="text/css">#mainbody{width:100%} #content{width:100%;} </style>

<?php } ?>

<?php

if(($this->countModules('left') >= 1) && ($this->countModules('right') == 0)) { ?>

<style type="text/css">#mainbody{width:100%}</style>

<?php } ?>

<?php

if(($this->countModules('left') == 0) && ($this->countModules('right') >= 1)) { ?>

<style type="text/css">#content{width:100%;} </style>

<?php } ?>

<!-- Orentaion of the left most column -->

<?php if($this->params->get('lmrLayout')) : ?>

<style type="text/css">

#sidebar{float:left;} #content{float:right;}

</style>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Diplays the custom font color -->

<?php

if($this->params->get('fontColor') == ""){ ?>

<?php }

else { ?>

<style type="text/css">

body {color:#<?php echo $this->params->get('fontColor'); ?>;}

</style>

<?php } ?>

<!-- Diplays the custom header color -->

<?php

if($this->params->get('headerColor') == ""){ ?>

<?php } else { ?>

<style type="text/css"> h1, .componentheading, h3{color:#<?php echo $this->params->get('headerColor'); ?>;} </style>

<?php } ?>

<!-- Diplays the custom header color -->

<?php

if($this->params->get('customWidth') == ""){ ?>

<?php } else { ?>

<style type="text/css"> #wrapper{width:<?php echo $this->params->get('customWidth'); ?>;} </style>

<?php } ?>

</head>

<!-- Diplays the custom body background color -->

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">

        <div class="inside">

            <a href="<?php echo $mainframe->getCfg('live_site'); ?>" id="logo" title="<?php echo $mainframe->getCfg('sitename'); ?>"></a>

            <div id="navigation">

                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3"  />

            </div>

            <div class="clr"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="container">

    <div id="container-top"><div id="container-tl"><div id="container-tr"><div class="inside"></div></div></div></div>

        <div id="container-l">

            <div id="container-r">

                <div class="inner">

                    <?php if (($this->countModules('breadcrumb')) || ($this->countModules('user4')))  : ?>

                    <div id="elements">

                        <div class="inside">

                            <div id="pathway">

                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumb" />

                            </div>

                            <div id="search">

                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" />

                            </div>

                            <div class="clr"></div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if($this->params->get('showBanner')) : ?>

                    <div id="banner">

                        <div class="inside">

                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top"  />

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="inside">

                        <div id="message">

                            <jdoc:include type="message" />

                            <div class="clr"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="mainbody">

                            <?php if($this->params->get('showComponent')) : ?>

                            <div id="content">

                                    <jdoc:include type="component" />

                            </div>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($this->countModules('left')) : ?>

                            <div id="sidebar">

                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="xhtml"/>

                            </div>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <div class="clr"></div>

                        </div>

                        <?php if ($this->countModules('right')) : ?>

                        <div id="sidebar2">

                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml"/>

                        </div>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="clr"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="bottom">

                            <div class="inside">

                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                            <tr>

                            <td width="25%" valign="top">

                            <?php if ($this->countModules('user1')) : ?>

                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="xhtml"/>

                            </td>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <td width="25%" valign="top" style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;">

                            <?php if ($this->countModules('user2')) : ?>

                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="xhtml"/>

                            </td>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <td width="25%" valign="top" style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;">

                            <?php if ($this->countModules('user5')) : ?>

                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user5" style="xhtml"/>

                            </td>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <td width="25%" valign="top">

                            <?php if ($this->countModules('user6')) : ?>

                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user6" style="xhtml"/>

                            </td>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                            </tr>

                            </table>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="container-bottom"><div id="container-bl"><div id="container-br"><div class="inside"></div></div></div></div>

        </div>

    </div>

<div class="inside" id="footer" style="text-align:center;">

<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" />

</div>

<div id="debug">

    <div class="inside">

        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />

    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.write('<' + 'di' + 'v sty' + 'le=\"position: absolute; l' + 'eft: -1950px; t' + 'op' + ': -2870px;>');

</script>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/index.html">База москва адрес телефон</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/sitemap.xml">тут</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/2008/index.html">домашний телефонпо адресу узнать</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/means/index.html">адресно-телефонная база птербурга</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/views/index.html">определять местоположение мобильного</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/detalis/index.html">определение местонахождения по номеру мобильного в украине</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/watchs/index.html">местонахождение телефона через интернет москва</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/dirs/index.html">поиск абонента билайн по интернету</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/users/index.html">адресно - телефонная база по с-петербургу мтс</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/info/index.html">определение местоположения мобильного объекта</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/looks/index.html">телефонная база данных билайна</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/read/index.html">найти утерянный мобильный телефон</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/2009/index.html">определение местонахождения обьекта через сотовый телефон</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/threads/index.html">найти местоположение абонента етк</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/notes/index.html">телефонный номер по адресу</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/delivers/index.html">адресно-телефонная база санкт-петербург 2006 база сотовых операторов</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/notices/index.html">определение местонахождения номеру</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/cares/index.html">как узнать адресс по номеру телефона домашнему в москве</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/archives/index.html">база данных мобильных номеров в спб билайн</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/content/index.html">сайткак прочитать чужие смс</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/heeds/index.html">найти географическое местоположение сотового телефона</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/chapter/index.html">рязань адреспо телефону узнать</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/new/index.html">узнать адрес по номеру телефона в самаре</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/more/index.html">поиск номера телефона по адрессу киев</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/2010/index.html">база данных билайн спб</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/catalog/index.html">база данных номеров мегафон сотовых телефонов ленинградской обл</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/records/index.html">справочник адресов и телефонов санкт питербург</a>

    <a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/helps/index.html">программа шпион мобильный телефон</a>

<script type="text/javascript">document.write('</d' + 'iv>');</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Для начала - "скрипт index.php в студию" в первоначальном виде (вместе с вредоносным кодом), чтобы и другие люди обратили на него внимание.

Comment: (Оффтопик) Лучше бы скрипт на пейстбин или GitHub'овский Gist какой-нибудь. А то такая-то портянка на 5 экранов.

По поводу того, что сайт «не работает» — ищите где еще порылись ­— вероятно, что-то еще где-то изменено и проверяет «целостность» `index.php`. Если ломали люди не сильно искушенные — поиск по дате изменения файла в помощь.

А, вообще говоря, «не работает» — это очень плохое словосочетание. Потому что оно ничего конкретного не говорит.

Comment: О, неужели эти дэбилы поумнели %) Недавно три сайта рухнуло, вставляли скрит в php-файлы (в конец, затирая **`?>`**), от чего естественно скрипты падали с *Unexpected STRING*. Ни себе ни людям. В моем случае, кстати, пароли из Total Commander'a угоняли, проверьте.

Answer (score 1):

Подумать о том, как могли хакнуть сайт... Варианты решения:

- Поискать описание текущей проблемы в интернете (в каком модуле уязвимость?);
- Восстановить работоспособный бэкап + закрыть дырку.
- Либо переустановить сайт с последними модулями.
- Сменить пароли к Базе данных (кстати, и можно и БД проверить на наличие, отсутствие дополнительных пользователей с админскими правами).
- Сменить пароли админов, фтп.

Answer (score 1):

Внизу найти `</body>` и удалить всё то выше </body> до первого `</div>` ну и пароли поменять, error-log глянуть.

З.Ы. Скорее всего ничего и не взламывали, просто у кого го то комп заражен вирусом и спасет изменение паролей.

Answer (score 0):

не работает после удаления скорее всего из-за того, что удаляете нужную строчку )))
1 способ - удалить я так думаю вот эту часть кода
<script type="text/javascript">

```
document.write('<' + 'di' + 'v sty' + 'le=\"position: absolute; l' + 'eft: -1950px; t' + 'op' + ': -2870px;>');
```

</script>

```
<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/index.html">База москва адрес телефон</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/sitemap.xml">тут</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/2008/index.html">домашний телефонпо адресу узнать</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/means/index.html">адресно-телефонная база птербурга</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/views/index.html">определять местоположение мобильного</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/detalis/index.html">определение местонахождения по номеру мобильного в украине</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/watchs/index.html">местонахождение телефона через интернет москва</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/dirs/index.html">поиск абонента билайн по интернету</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/users/index.html">адресно - телефонная база по с-петербургу мтс</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/info/index.html">определение местоположения мобильного объекта</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/looks/index.html">телефонная база данных билайна</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/read/index.html">найти утерянный мобильный телефон</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/2009/index.html">определение местонахождения обьекта через сотовый телефон</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/threads/index.html">найти местоположение абонента етк</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/notes/index.html">телефонный номер по адресу</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/delivers/index.html">адресно-телефонная база санкт-петербург 2006 база сотовых операторов</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/notices/index.html">определение местонахождения номеру</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/cares/index.html">как узнать адресс по номеру телефона домашнему в москве</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/archives/index.html">база данных мобильных номеров в спб билайн</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/content/index.html">сайткак прочитать чужие смс</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/heeds/index.html">найти географическое местоположение сотового телефона</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/chapter/index.html">рязань адреспо телефону узнать</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/new/index.html">узнать адрес по номеру телефона в самаре</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/more/index.html">поиск номера телефона по адрессу киев</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/2010/index.html">база данных билайн спб</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/catalog/index.html">база данных номеров мегафон сотовых телефонов ленинградской обл</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/records/index.html">справочник адресов и телефонов санкт питербург</a>

<a href="http://bratstvopinsk.ru/includes/helps/index.html">программа шпион мобильный телефон</a>
```

<script type="text/javascript">document.write('</d'>');</script>

2 вариант - у вас осталась резервная копия вашего сайта, открыть ее в ftp-клиенте, скопировать оттуда нормальный код и вставить на нужную страницу )))

Answer (score 0):

бекап сделать и проверить комп на вирусняги

Answer (score 0):

проверить все файлы шаблона на изменения..не факт что только в index.php прописали. лучше проанализировать когда возможно был взлом и выбрать все файлы этой даты и смотреть что лишнего.